# SQL Query to show all results before current month

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in Oracle with columns: [DATEID date, COUNT_OF_PHOTOS int]
This table basically represents how many photos were uploaded per day.

I have a query that summarizes the number of photos uploaded per month:

```
select extract(year from dateid) as year, extract(month from dateid) as month, count(1) as Photos
from picture_table
group by extract(year from dateid), extract(month from dateid)
order by 1, 2
```

This does what I want, but I would like to run this query at the beginning of each month, lets say 07-02-2012, and have all data EXCLUDING the current month. How would I add a WHERE clause that ignores all entries that have a date equal to the current year+month?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
where to_char(dateid, 'YYYY-MM') <> to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM')
```

Answer (score 1):

To preserve any indexing strategy you may have on `dateid`:

```
select extract(year from dateid) as year, extract(month from dateid) as month, count(1) as Photos
from picture_table
WHERE (dateid < TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM') OR dateid >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),1))
group by extract(year from dateid), extract(month from dateid)
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: The requirement is to count photos which have been uploaded prior to the current month.  Therefore your second filter is unnecessary.  It is possible to take future-proofing too far :)

Comment: Your point about indexing strategy is a complex one.  As the query currently stands it can be solved entirely from an index on DATEID without touching the table at all.  However if other columns are added to the projection then it will be far more efficient to do a full table scan rather than use an index (as there wiull be considerably more records which aren't for the current month).